# How to create a readstream with a buffer using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, buffer, fs, node-streams

I have this json:

```
var myJSON = '{"kind": "person", "fullName": "Rivka3"}';
```

I'm trying to uploed it to bigquery, using createReadStream.
when I save it localy I succeed:

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/bq_json_file_new.json", myJSON, function(err){});
fs.createReadStream("/tmp/bq_json_file_new.json")
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream(metadata))
  .on('complete', function(job) {
    job
      .on('error', console.log)
      .on('complete', function(metadata) {
        console.log('job completed', metadata);
      });
  });
```

now I'm trying to do this without saving it localy - using a buffer:

```
fs.createReadStream(new Buffer(myJSON, "utf8"))
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream(metadata))
  .on('complete', function(job) {
    job
      .on('error', console.log)
      .on('complete', function(metadata) {
        console.log('job completed', metadata);
      });
  });
```

but i recieve this error:

```
fs.js:575
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),

TypeError: path must be a string
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

using `stream` solves the problem:

```
var stream = require('stream');

var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

bufferStream.end(new Buffer(myJSON));

bufferStream.pipe(table.createWriteStream(metadata))
                   .on('complete', function(job) {
                     job
                       .on('error', console.log)
                       .on('complete', function(metadata) {
                         console.log('job completed', metadata);
                       });
                   });
```